Elastic Beanstalk - Container Commands fail
I am really hitting my head now against the wall since i am stuck the whole day now with deploying an Angular SSR application (version 17) to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Maybe somebody of you knows whats wrong with this one:
As mentioned I am trying to deploy my Angular Application to Elastic Beanstalk through eb deploy. Since I figured that because of SSR, it needs to be deployed through custom scripts which you can configure with Procfile and node commands. I therefore have the following setup:
root/Procfile:
web: node dist/application/server/server.mjs
root/.ebextensions>01_node_commands.config
container_commands:
  00_build_app:
    command: "npm run build -- --configuration=production"

When running eb deploy, I get the following error in the cfn-init.log:

Unhandled exception during build: Command 00_build_app failed

I am trying to run this container command to have the browser/server structure later, to run the command in Procfile
I cant figure out whats wrong here and wasnt able to find a tutorial/docs that explains if maybe the structure changed of the builds.
I also tried this before:
If i exclude the container_commands it works, but it wont start since some modules fail (I guess thats another problem and happens of the ssr structure maybe)
But the same error, but no feedback. Why?
Btw, if someone has a better to get my Angular application in the cloud, I am open for ideas. Just got introduced to the topic :)

login to the launched EB instance and run this command manually. Easiest way to get the actual error

I tried it, but same error unfortunate. It does not really produce a meaningful output

what do you mean? if you run npm run build it either works, or you get an error why it doesn't. what do you mean "same error"? Running npm can't give you "Command 00_build_app failed"
